# Home Sharing songs greyed out on iPad

Tags: itunes, home-sharing

I connected my iPad to Home Sharing from my laptop. I can play music by pressing shuffle play and pressing next, however I cannot choose which song to play because it is either greyed out (inside albums/artists/etc.) or it is regular but pressing it does nothing (Songs, playlists).

Comment: I assume you tried the obvious, power cycle the iPad. I mention it because I forget that even they need it sometimes =]

Comment: @Tyson - I did and now it just says "Unable to turn on Home Sharing"

Answer (score 1):

You have to fulfill 3 prerequisites:

1- WiFi has to be on

2- The power plug has to be in (Charger)

3- You must be on same network